# Search attribute with approximate value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a JavaScript element ID and I only know the title.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('[title="My Workforce"]');

var id = x.getAttribute('id');
```

I don't know how to write the title so that it is any approximation of "My Workforce". I have tried using "*" (as in `"*My Workforce*"`) but it didn't work. `querySelectorAll()` looks for an exact match.

Comment: In the above, I have tried to use the asterix wildcard, like this "\*My Workforce\*", but it didn't help

Comment: If by "any approximation", you're saying you want to search for the substring in the value, use `title*="My Workforce"`

Comment: squint is correct. BTW, you probably want `querySelector()`, otherwise you'll need to use `x[0]` once you get the desired results from `querySelectorAll()` - it returns a *list* of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector()` instead. This allows the use of wildcards, like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/xtukey8o/

```
document.querySelector('[title*="My Workforce"]')
```